# Pickle error when submitting task using dask

Tags: python, dask, dask-distributed

I am trying to execute a simple task(an instance method) using dask(async) framework but it fails with serialization error.

Can someone point me in right direction.

Here is the code that I am running:

```
from dask.distributed import Client, as_completed
import time

class DaskConnect:

def __init__(self):
    print("Initialized:",self.__class__.__name__)
    self.scheduler_host="192.168.0.4"
    self.scheduler_port="8786"

def connect(self):
    self.client = Client(self.scheduler_host+":"+self.scheduler_port)
    # self.client = Client()
    return self.client

def disconnect(self):
    self.client.close()

class TestDask:
def __init__(self):
    print("Initialized:",self.__class__.__name__)
    self.dask_client=DaskConnect().connect()

def do_task(self,msg):
    time.sleep(30)
    return msg

def run(self):
    tasks=[1]
    # tasks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    futures=[]
    for task in tasks:
        print("Submitting:",task)
        future = self.dask_client.submit(self.do_task, "Task:"+str(task))
        futures.append(future)

    for future in as_completed(futures):
        result = future.result()
        print("Result",result)

TestDask().run()
```

Error:

> distributed.protocol.pickle - INFO - Failed to serialize main.TestDask object at 0x101c408d0>>.
>   Exception: can't pickle select.kqueue objects Traceback (most recent
>   call last):

Answer (score 11):

Dask Clients aren't currently serializable.  Any object that contains a Dask Client will also not be serializable.  Generally it is challenge to serialize anything that contains active network connections, locks, etc..

Perhaps there is another approach to your problem?

Comment: Thanks @MR for pointing in right direction. Changing client from instance variable to local variable in function run solved the problem.